# Pausing a CountDownTimer whilst another one is running in Android Studio, then resuming it when the other one ends?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I have two CountDownTimers in my program: a 4 second one, and 24 second one. I want the longer timer to be paused for every 4 seconds the shorter timer is running. Then when the short timer finishes, the long timer begins counting down. Here's the code for the two timers:

```
final CountDownTimer loop = new CountDownTimer(4000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    prompt.setText(" Enter the number");
                    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    input.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    input.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                                switch (keyCode) {
                                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                                        Editable answer = input.getText();
                                        int finalAnswer = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(answer));
                                        int finalLoadG1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.getText()));
                                        input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                        if (finalAnswer == finalLoadG1) {
                                            score++;
                                        }

                                        number.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        int loadG1 = generateG1.nextInt(1000000)+10000;
                                        number.setText(""+loadG1);
                                        input.getText().clear();

                                        start();

                                        return true;
                                    default:
                                }
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
                }.start();


            new CountDownTimer(24000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outcome);
                    result.setText("Score: "+ score);
                    TextView prompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prompt);
                    prompt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterAnswer);
                    input.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    loop.cancel();
                    number.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }.start();
```

I thought about naming the longer timer, then putting name.pause() in the onTick for the shorter timer. Issue is, because the longer timer is written after the shorter one, it's name is not recognizable before it has been initialized. Java reads things in order, right? Or is that all languages?

If anyone could help me I'd be grateful, many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you posted the exact same question the other day.

Comment: I'm just saying there is no point "flooding" your question.

Comment: @Anto If you think 2 is a flood, you should read up on spam bots. I understand your point, although I'm in need of an answer and as soon as one is posted (no matter how useless), my question is usually ignored. Take it to be this site's algorithm. Despite how many skilled programmers there are here, my question may just end up being ignored again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Vector;

class LongTimer extends Thread {

    static final int MAXQUEUE = 5;
    private Vector messages = new Vector();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    putMessage();
                    sleep(4000);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        private synchronized void putMessage() throws InterruptedException {
            while (messages.size() == MAXQUEUE) {
                wait();
            }
            messages.addElement(new java.util.Date().toString());
            System.out.println("put message");
            notify();
            //Later, when the necessary event happens, the thread that is running it calls notify() from a block synchronized on the same object.
        }

        // Called by short timer
        public synchronized String getMessage() throws InterruptedException {
            notify();
            while (messages.size() == 0) {
                wait();//By executing wait() from a synchronized block, a thread gives up its hold on the lock and goes to sleep.
            }
            String message = (String) messages.firstElement();
            messages.removeElement(message);
            return message;
        }
    }

    class ShortTimer extends Thread {

        LongTimer producer;

        ShortTimer(LongTimer p) {
            producer = p;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    String message = producer.getMessage();
                    System.out.println("Got message: " + message);
                    //sleep(200);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            LongTimer producer = new LongTimer();
            producer.start();
            new ShortTimer(producer).start();
        }        
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.